# Overflow problems with summing squares

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm tackling an assignment which asks us to:

Write a program in MIPS assembly which, given a memory address in `$a0` to the first element of an array of n 32-bit unsigned numbers (n is stored in `$a1`), it should square each one of them and sum the squares. The 32 most significant bits should be returned on `$v1`, while the least significant ones on `$v0`.

Special returns (on `v0`):

- Zero if the array has no elements (n = 0)
- DEADBEEF (hex) = 3735928559 (dec) if the result can't fit in 64 bits.

What I've done so far: (the input is handled by separate, given to us code)

```
squaredSum:
            beq     $t5, $zero, getRetAddr  # if $t5 (caller's ret. addr.) is zero (ie. first time the function is called, then get the caller's ret. addr.)  
            move    $t0, $a1                # $t0: array size (we want to turn it into bytes)
            sll     $t0, $t0, 2             # multiply array size by 4, so we get the total number of bytes (2 left bitwise shifts)
            beq     $t1, $t0, sumExit       # if offset ($t1) = bytes, then end of array, so we terminate (jump to "exit" label)
            add     $t2, $t1, $a0           # $t2: address from which we start reading (base + offset)
            lw      $t3, 0($t2)             # $t3: the number to be squared is loaded here
            mult    $t3, $t3                # multiply $t3 with itself (square), result of multiplication goes to internal registers Hi and Lo
            mfhi    $t8                     # load HI's contents into $t8
            mflo    $t9                     # load LO's contents into $t9
            addi    $t1, $t1, 4             # add 4 to offset (move to next element, since numbers are 32bit)
            jal     adduover                # call adduover to sum the newly found square
            b       squaredSum              # go back to the beginning of the loop

adduover:
            add    $t7, $t7, $t9            # add Lo to $t7
            add    $t6, $t6, $t8            # add Hi to $t6
            blt    $t7, $t9, correction     # if total sum of Lo is lower than Lo before summation (32bit overflow) then jump to label "correction"
            blt    $t6, $t8, overflow       # if total sum of Hi is lower than before summation (64bit overflow) then jump to label "overflow"s
            jr     $ra

correction:
            addi    $t8, $t8, 1             # add 1 to the most significant bits (we made a full circle)
            jr      $ra                     # continue with adduover

overflow:
            li      $v0, 3735928559         # return as result (0x00000000DEADBEEF) in case of 64-bit overflow
            jr      $ra                     # continue with adduover

getRetAddr:
            move    $t5, $ra                # get the return addr. of squareSum's caller, because it gets overwritten during execution
            j       squaredSum              # continue with squaredSum

sumExit:
            move $v0, $t9                   # send least significant 32 bits to $v0 (exercise output)
            move $v1, $t8                   # same as above for most significant

                jr   $t5                        # return to squaredsum's caller's address
```

For input of small numbers (even in large arrays) the program works as intended. My problem is that when I input a large number (ie. 2000000000), during the multiplication the `lo` register overflows and flips to minus, which implies that everything stored in `lo` gets signed, while I want it to be unsigned in order to return to 0 and count upwards. Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks for your time.

PS: FYI, I'm using MARS for interpreting the code.

Comment: You're using unsigned numbers, so the high bit is *not* a sign bit.  Signed vs. unsigned is a matter of interpretation only; tell your debugger to print it unsigned, or just ignore the bogus signed-decimal value and look at the hex.

Comment: Well, that's a problem. MARS seems to force interpreting the result as signed, because when assembling it throws an exception of arithmetic overflow, and I can't find anything that resembles an option to change this interpretation.

Comment: Lo did not overflow.  It merely *looks* like it did, 0x9D900000 has the high bit set.  Don't get confused by the what the debugger or emulator tells you, if it has the option to display register values as unsigned then you'll favor using it.  If not then just verify the end-result.

Comment: @lightspot21: Are you using `add` instead of `addu`?  (your code isn't in your question; put it in a code-block so people can look at it).  MIPS has special signed-add instructions that trap on signed overflow.  Don't use them on unsigned data that can be `>= 2^31`.  `addu` / `addui` is the normal wrapping instead of trapping instruction.

Comment: Terminology: unless you have a MARS bug or limitation, it doesn't overflow when you assemble; it's when you *run* in the simulator.  (Also, MARS doesn't interpret your asm source; it assembles and then runs the MIPS machine code in its MIPS emulator).