# MIPS assembly: branches don't seem to work (MARS)

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm working on an assignment (described here: [Overflow problems with summing squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49965565/overflow-problems-with-summing-squares?noredirect=1#comment86947010_49965565)) and I've solved the problem with the overflows. The new problem now is that MARS doesn't want to follow the branches, even when the conditions for them are met, according always to MARS.

Code here:

```
squaredSum: 
        beq     $t5, $zero, getRetAddr  # if $t5 (caller's ret. addr.) is zero (ie. first time the function is called, then get the caller's ret. addr.)   
        move    $t0, $a1                # $t0: array size (we want to turn it into bytes)
        sll     $t0, $t0, 2             # multiply array size by 4, so we get the total number of bytes (2 left bitwise shifts)
        beq     $t1, $t0, sumExit       # if offset ($t1) = bytes, then end of array, so we terminate (jump to "exit" label)
        addu    $t2, $t1, $a0           # $t2: address from which we start reading (base + offset)
        lw      $t3, 0($t2)             # $t3: the number to be squared is loaded here
        multu   $t3, $t3                # multiply $t3 with itself (square), result of multiplication goes to internal registers HI and LO
        mfhi    $t8         # load HI's contents into $t8
        mflo    $t9         # load LO's contents into $t9
        addiu   $t1, $t1, 4             # add 4 to offset (move to next element, since numbers are 32bit)
        jal     adduover                # call adduover to sum the newly found square
        j       squaredSum              # go back to the beginning of the loop

adduover:
        addu    $t7, $t7, $t9           # add LO to $t7
        addu    $t6, $t6, $t8           # add HI to $t6
        *blt     $t7, $t9, correction*           # if total sum of LO is lower than LO before summation (32-bit overflow) then jump to label "correction"
        *blt     $t6, $t8, overflow*      # if total sum of HI is lower than HI before summation (64-bit overflow) then jump to label "overflow"
        jr      $ra                     # get back to squaredSum

correction:
        addiu   $t6, $t6, 1             # add 1 to the most significant bits (we made a full circle)
        blt     $t6, $t8, overflow      # check once more for 64-bit overflow after the addition
        jr      $ra                     # get back to squaredSum

overflow:
        li      $v0, 3735928559         # return as result (0x00000000DEADBEEF) in case of 64-bit overflow
        j       sumExit                 # jump to sumExit

getRetAddr:
        move    $t5, $ra                # get the return addr. of squareSum's caller, because it gets overwritten during execution
        j       squaredSum              # continue with squaredSum

sumExit:
        move    $v0, $t7                # send least significant 32 bits to $v0 (exercise output)
        move    $v1, $t6                # same as above for most significant 
        jr  $t5                     # return to squaredSum's caller's address
```

Comment: Which branch is not taken, and for what input. Ideally, show register contents at the branch and that it does not jump.

Comment: do you code for real MIPS CPU with branch delay slot, or do you write code for MARS only with delayed branching switched OFF? Do you have the delay slot switched OFF? From the source (I gave it 3 second look) it looks like your code is not targetting real MIPS, ignoring the delay slot, so verify you have MARS set up to this configuration (making it unreal, but easier for new programmers).

Comment: @Ped7g Delayed branching is off, when turning it on the program doesn't assemble.

Comment: @Jester I've marked with asterisks the branches that aren't taken, when inputting `0x3b200000` in `$t7` and `0x9d900000` on `$t9`.

Comment: `blt` is signed, as such `0x9d900000` is treated as a negative number so `0x3b200000` is not less. Use `bltu`.

Comment: you can also avoid branching for the correction: `sltu $at, $t7, $t9` `addu $t6, $t6, $at` .. done, t6 corrected.

Comment: working example (not checking for total overflow of sum): https://stackoverflow.com/q/49976951/4271923  ... looks like there's suddenly many people asking about MIPS summing squares, I wonder how that may happened... probably some celebrity tweeted something about MIPS assembly being cool... hmmm.

Comment: @Jester I didn't know there was such an instruction for unsigned branching. Many thanks!